# Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet' or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, reference

I have an Asp.net project, and in said projects web.config i have

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">      
      <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

(already followed a should-be-fix from another post)
but on runtime i get

```
Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

When I open up the properties of my project, and go to refrences, i can see that there is a  `DotNetOpenAuth.Core` entry, a `DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet` entry, a `DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth` entry,a `DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer` entry, a `DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId` entry, and a `DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty` entry, and theyre all set to Copy Local = true. 
What could possibly be going wrong?

EDIT:
heres the full error log, looks like its still trying to load 4.3.0.0 to me

```
    Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet' could not be loaded.


    === Pre-bind state information ===
    LOG: User = MegaBadTouch\James
    LOG: DisplayName = DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet
     (Partial)
    WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
    WRN: Assembly Name: DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet | Domain ID: 2
    WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
    WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
    WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
    WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
    WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
    LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/James/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/Archive/Archive/
    LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\James\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Archive\Archive\bin
    Calling assembly : (Unknown).
    ===
    LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
    LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\James\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Archive\Archive\web.config
    LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\James\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
    LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
    LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/James/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/47d58003/7c1d4013/DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.DLL.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/James/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/47d58003/7c1d4013/DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet/DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.DLL.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/James/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/Archive/Archive/bin/DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.DLL.
    LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\James\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Archive\Archive\web.config
    LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\James\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
    LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
    LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 4.0.0.0 redirected to 4.1.0.0.
    LOG: Post-policy reference: DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/James/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/47d58003/7c1d4013/DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.DLL.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/James/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/47d58003/7c1d4013/DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet/DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.DLL.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/James/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/Archive/Archive/bin/DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.DLL.
    WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
    ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

    Stack Trace: 


    [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]

    [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
       System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
       System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +34
       System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
       System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
       System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +16
       System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
       System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38

    [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
       System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +752
       System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +218
       System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
       System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
       System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +91
       System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath) +258
       System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +135
       System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +516

    [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
       System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9874840
       System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
       System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

Comment: Post-policy reference: DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246. 4.0 being redirected to 4.1, fails the load chain.

Comment: Pardon? what do you mean?

Comment: DOtNetOpenAth.AspNet.dll is required, it it trying to load a 4.1 version but that doesn't seem to be available. Check which version you have and add a redirect for it if required (donno if they are compatible though)

Comment: surely the 'oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0"' tags should make it load whatever is available though?

Comment: Its picking up another policy for sure. it's being redirected to 4.1. Double check if your configuration is actually used?

Comment: How would i check that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error It was that one of the references that you have added might have got missed . all you need to do is drop the references and add them back manually . or copy your code into a new solution it would work .I copied my code into a " new empty project  " and ran it . it had no problems then .

Open a new empty project with new classes and aspx and copy just your code into it , it should work .

Answer (score -1):

I changed the versions to 4.1.0.0 and it worked for me.

```
   <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780CCD10D57B246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780CCD10D57B246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
```